# Reset my android device password using android device manager

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lock-screens, password, android-device-manager

I'm android Marshmallow user. and I want to resent my password using android device manager. I signed in my google account and went to google's android device manager and it's not showing any option to reset the password.

[image: ADM window]

I went through some tutorial on google and they've shown this option with screenshot. But i'm enable to find it right now. can somebody pls help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Resetting pattern / password using ADM is possible for devices [running 4.4 or lower only](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3388218?hl=en) . Also see this [on Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/RxHohpnDWjM)

Your way out is to reset your device after logging out of the Google account to prevent factory reset protection issues or keep guessing the password till you get it right

Answer (score 0):

Here’s [how to Unlock your Android device using Android Device Manager](https://www.cyclonis.com/how-unlock-android-phone-without-data-loss-if-forgot-password/).

1. Get on your PC or borrow a phone or tablet from a friend and go to "[Forwarding ...](https://www.google.com/android/find)".
2. Sign into your Google account that you use on your locked phone.
3. Choose the phone you want to attack in Android Device Manager.
   Choose "Lock".
4. A window will appear, which will prompt you for a password. Enter a new password.
5. Hit "Lock" a second time.
6. You'll get a confirmation message if everything went right.
7. Unlock your phone with the new password.
8. Finally, go to your phone's settings and remove the new password unless you want to keep using it.
9. Unlock your Android lock screen pattern with your Google Login (only works on Android 4.4 and older versions).

Comment: However the asker is running Android 6.0 Marshmallow.